# Routing Error, no route matches[post] "/look/at"

Tags: forms, post, routes, helper

I am exercising to use form_helper but it does not work.
I made look controller and input, at actions.

In my input view

## Working with Text Fields

This Ruby on Rails application lets you read data from text fields.
    
    <%= form_tag ("/look/at") do %>
    Please enter your name.
    
    <%= text_field_tag("text1") %>
    
    
    <%= submit_tag("submit")%>
    <% end %>

In my at view

## Using HTML Control Shortcuts

This application uses Rail HTML control shortcuts.
    
    
    Your name is <%= @data %>

In my routes.rb
    Textfields2::Application.routes.draw do
    get "look/at"
    get "look/input"

In my look controller
     class LookController < ApplicationController
     def at
     @data = params[:text1]
     end

```
 def input
 end
 end
```

what is problem??

one more question!
My book is "Beginning Ruby on Rails" written by "Steven Holzner". I think this book is written for Rails3.
And the code up there is same as the code in the book. Does the problem occurs because of the difference rails3 and 4?

rake routes result

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
```

look_at GET /look/at(.:format)    look#at
look_input GET /look/input(.:format) look#input

Comment: Please do rake routes in command line and post the results here. That will clearly tell you whether this route is configured or not

Comment: @vigneshre I can not understand what you mean...cause I am new...what is rake routes?

Comment: Please go to the command line and go to your rails app top directory and type "rake routes" and give the output here

Comment: @vigneshre rake routes result

    Prefix Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
   look_at GET /look/at(.:format)    look#at
look_input GET /look/input(.:format) look#input

Comment: ok.Please replace form_tag ("/look/at") with form_tag (look_at_path), it should work.

Comment: @vigneshre no same error occurs...

Comment: your routes are defined for `GET` but you car calling it via `POST`, replace `get` with `post` in routes file

Comment: cool..added it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

your routes are defined for GET but you car calling it via POST, replace get with post in routes file